# Axis label number format vs labelExpr with format()

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I want to apply a number formatting and a string join to the axis labels, but I bumped into some weird behavior.

When I want to apply a format to an axis label, using `format='~s'` or `labelExpr="format()"` give different results. Also it is not clear what exactly `datum.values` and `datum.labels` returns as it *sometimes* works with labels.
If the scale is logarithmic, the issues are even more unclear to me; seems `datum.values` returns the *minor ticks* only or something.
Am I missing something obvious?

```py
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = np.random.randint(1,1e6,1000)
y = np.linspace(1,1e6,1000)
x = np.linspace(1,1e3,1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x=alt.X('x:Q'),
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='~s', )),
).properties(width=300, height=200)

plot1 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="format(datum.value,'~s')+' ppm'"))
)

plot2 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="datum.value +' ppm'", format='~s'))
)

plot3 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="datum.label +' ppm'", format='~s'))
)

plot4 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="format(datum.label, '~s') +' ppm'"))
)

(base | plot1 | plot2) & (plot3 | plot4)
```

[image: plots]

```py
base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x=alt.X('x:Q'),
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(format='~s', )),
).properties(width=300, height=200)

plot1 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="format(datum.value,'~s')+' ppm'"))
)

plot2 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="datum.value +' ppm'", format='~s'))
)

plot3 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="datum.label +' ppm'", format='~s'))
)

plot4 = base.encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="format(datum.label, '~s') +' ppm'"))
)

(base | plot1 | plot2) & (plot3 | plot4)
```

[image]